Tensorflow versus deeplearning4j
For ML frameworks one would think Tensorflow would be the 800# gorilla in the room. I work in a Java shop and Tensorflow's Java support seems to be somewhere between terrible and awful, even for just running models after they are created and tuned in Python.
Java's DeepLearning4j (DL4J) doesn't even have a tag on this site.
What's a reasonable way forward?
